# Cannot create a VoIP call using Microsoft Graph and Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to replace an existing click to dial functionality in a .NET application that currently uses "Skype For Business/Lync" and switch it to "Microsoft Teams". It does not look as though there is many examples of this online. The examples I have found do not seem to work for me. The example to shows up in multiple sources is below:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                                                                                .Create(clientId)
                                                                                .WithTenantId(tenantID)
                                                                                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                                                                                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var call = new Call
            {
                CallbackUri = redirectUri,
                Targets = new List<InvitationParticipantInfo>()
            {
                new InvitationParticipantInfo
                {
                    Identity = new IdentitySet
                    {
                        User = new Identity
                        {
                            DisplayName = "John",
                            Id = userId
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
                RequestedModalities = new List<Modality>()
            {
                Modality.Audio
            },
                MediaConfig = new ServiceHostedMediaConfig
                {
                }
            };

            var response = graphClient.Communications.Calls
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(call).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This code ultimately returns an error

```
Message: {"errorCode":"7503","message":"Application is not registered in our store.","instanceAnnotations":[]}
```

There is not much documentation on this error. I have registered a bot in Azure Active Directory and plugged in all the necessary values into the variables in the snippen above.

I have also attempted to run this code in Postman using the example in this [link](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/application-post-calls.md#tab/http) which also contains the C# example. Postman returns the exact same error.

I can also confirm I have the Calls.Initialte API permissions granted with Admin consent.

[image]
Has anyone made a successful outgoing call in C# via Microsoft Graph/Teams?

Comment: Could you please check the permission's have admin consent?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm I have the Admin  Consent for the Calls.Initiate API. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Calls.JoinGroupCallsasGuest.All, Calls.JoinGroupCalls.All, Calls.Initiate.All, Calls.InitiateGroupCalls.All Do you have consent to a the mentioned permission i can't see them, i can see only two..For a call with app-hosted media, you need the Calls.AccessMedia.All permission in addition to one of the permissions listed

Comment: Could you please confirm, if you are still facing this issue?

Comment: Hi @Trinetra-MSFT, thanks for your help so far. I had all call permissions added and granted for the purpose of the test which was not successful. The same error was produced "Application is not registered in our store."

Comment: Did you enabled [calling feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot) for your bot while registering bot?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT, thank you very much it was a combination of having the correct Calls api permissions, enable calling on the azure bot as well as modifying the examples provided on Microsoft's website. If the tenantId is not provided in the call payload you will get another error stating that the tenanId ae mismatched. If you can post your comments as an answer I will happily attribute the solution to you. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure Thanks Glad to know Issue is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-create-peer-to-peer-voip-call-with-service-hosted-media) enables your Bot to create peer to peer or group call, You need to [register your calling Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot) and assign the following Application permissions:

```
Calls.JoinGroupCallsasGuest.All, Calls.JoinGroupCalls.All, 
Calls.Initiate.All, Calls.InitiateGroupCalls.All
```

**1. To Create peer-to-peer VoIP call with service hosted media**

```
Note: This call needs the Calls.Initiate.All Application permission.
```

while registering your Bot you need enable the [calling feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot#creating-a-new-bot-or-adding-calling-capabilities-to-an-existing-bot) for your Bot and to make your bot to participate in audio and video call You need to set `supportsCalling` and `supportsVideo` to `true` within your app manifest.